# Java Netbeans fetching query result into JLabels

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans

I have a `JFrame form` which asks the user to insert for example his name then it shows him the addresses of all houses he owns (user may own more than one house).

However, since i dunno how many result the query will come out with, i created a function of type vector and stored the data into it, then returned the vector. At the JFrame form i'm doing something like this.

```
Vector<String> data = User.getHouse(userName.getText());
        if (data.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Houses were found!");
        }
        else {
           for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
              {
                 System.out.println(data.elementAt(i));
                 houses.setText(data.elementAt(i));
                 houses2.setText(data.elementAt(i+1));
                }
            }
```

the function code:

```
  public static Vector<String> getHouse(String playerName) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection con = DBConnect.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement getId = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Player_Id from PLAYERS WHERE Name = ?");
    getId.setString(1, playerName);
    ResultSet y = getId.executeQuery();
    if(y.next())
    {
        id = y.getString("Player_id");
        System.out.println("playerID => " + id);
    }
    System.out.println("playerName => " + playerName);

    PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("SELECT House_Name FROM HOUSES WHERE Player_Id = ?");
    s.setString(1, id);
    System.out.println("getHouse => Query");
    ResultSet x = s.executeQuery();
    Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();
    while(x.next())
    {
        data.addElement(x.getString("House_Name"));
    }
    return data;
}
```

(query returns 2 rows). How can i correctly set the `JLabel text` with the query result?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). Hard code some data to replace the DB.  2) Store the result in a `JTable`, or each row in a `JList` (then show the details of whatever row of the list is selected).

Comment: @MyCloud you are showing data in loop due to that it will always show last element data to your label house & for next it will trigger an exception

Comment: @Andrew here is the function code which i'm working on http://pastebin.com/2r2SvYef
Now you have the function and at my post you got how i'm actually calling it. hopefully this makes things clear. I appreciate your suggestion but first, i would like to make it work for the JLabel.

Comment: @Swapnill Yes, thanks for your notice, the loop at it's first iteration will result the JLabel to equal the first row but eventually it will end up with the 2nd row as you mentioned.

Comment: *"hopefully this makes things clear."*  I (and most other people) won't follow links.  If the code at the link is an MCVE, [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23564735/edit) and add it.

Comment: @Andrew Updated the question, feel free to check it.

Comment: Feel free to follow my advice anytime...